# Call PHP function in a class from a HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have a class which is maintain guest information. So in that class I have following method to insert guest data into a `guest_info` table

```
require_once "BaseModel.php";

class GuestModel extends BaseModel
{
    public static $table = "guest_info";

    public static function guestInfoFormData(){
         $title = $_POST['title'];
         $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
         $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
         $nicpassport = $_POST['nicpassport'];
         $contactnumber = $_POST['contactnumber'];
         $addressline1 = $_POST['addressline1'];
         $addressline2 = $_POST['addressline2'];
         $addressline3 = $_POST['addressline3'];
         $country = $_POST['country'];
         $guestinfo = array($title,$firstname,$firstname,$nicpassport,$addressline1,$addressline2,$addressline3,$country);
         insertInto($guestinfo);
    }
}
```

How can I call this method from my HTML form and pass the guest data to it?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php GuestModel::guestInfoFormData(); ?>
```

ensure the `GuestModel` class is required / included before that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GuestModel::guestInfoFormData()`, but you can't do it in a `html` file, it has to be a php file.

Don't forget to escape all input values, now you pass all user input to `insertInto`, so you have to escape the data before using them in a sql query to prevent sql injections.

Btw: Why you create a class, when you call a global function from it? Maybe it's a good idea to move the global function `insertInto` into this (or another, better) class :)

Comment: I put `insertInto` method inside my `BaseModel` class, so i can use it for my other data insertions, Is it a bad idea?

Comment: No, that sounds like a reasonable model, but then you can't use it as a global function, you need to call it like: `self::inertInto()`, and it has to be a static method, too. If it is a non-static method, you'll get a php strict standards error, but it will not interrupt the script. Is there a reason why you use this function statically? Maybe you want to create a new instance of the class and use the function in a context? :)

Comment: Yes `insertInto` is a static method.I missed the class name thanks for remind it. and I put `GuestModel::guestInfoFormData()` but now i cannot access `$_POST['title'];` inside the method :(